# It's like a whole secret life 'for' you

Tags: prepositions

I'm always confused about of and for. :( -- From a scene of *New Girl*, why didn't she say it's like a whole secret life 'of' you? Would appreciate if you could explain what it means if she said it this way (even if it wouldn't make sense)

Answer (score 1):

In this instance, 'for' denotes attribution as in

> It's a whole new experience for you.

It's a common turn of phrase, especially between people of equal status who are bantering.

Answer (score -1):

In American English, one could correctly say, **"It's like a whole secret *side* of you,"** but not **"It's like a whole secret *life* of you."** You could also correctly say, **"It's like a whole secret life *of yours* that you keep hidden from me."** But "life of you" just doesn't work.